# Is tf.compat.v1.layers.AveragePooling2D the same than tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm just started to learn Tensorflow and I have found an example in Tensorflow 1.x that I think it is very difficult to migrate to Tensorflow 2.x, so I have decided to use it in its original version.

You can find the code on this github: [Omniglot Character Set Classification Using Prototypical Network](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/Chapter03/3.3%20Omniglot%20Character%20set%20classification%20using%20Prototypical%20Network.ipynb)

I want to change the Flatten layer with a Global average pooling layer to this code:

```
def get_embeddings(support_set, h_dim, z_dim, reuse=False):

    net = convolution_block(support_set, h_dim)
    net = convolution_block(net, h_dim)
    net = convolution_block(net, h_dim) 
    net = convolution_block(net, z_dim) 
    net = tf.compat.v1.layers.flatten(net)

    return net
```

On Tensorflow 2.x, I know that the function I want to use is [GlobalAveragePooling2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling2D), but I can't find a function with the same name on Tensorflow 1.x. I have found this [AveragePooling2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/layers/AveragePooling2D).

Is AveragePooling2D the same a GlobalAveragePooling2D?

Answer (score 1):

if you can't access to [GlobalAveragePooling2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling2D#aliases), remember that you can do it simply defining your own lambda layer to do the same operation

```
x = np.random.uniform(0,1, (2,224,224,3)).astype('float32')

GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# the same as
Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=[1,2]))(x)
```